# How can I determine the subscription type of a Facebook friend?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

A little while ago, I went through and [manually changed the subscription](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=188147907920585) type of many of my friends on Facebook.

I would now like to review what types of updates my feed displays from all my friends.

Ideally, I'd like 3 lists, friends which are set to:

1. All Updates
2. Most Updates
3. Only Important

Is there a way to use FQL to determine this?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no API which returns the News Feed options you've defined for friends. 
You can return the friends lists you've defined (/me/friendlists) but not the specific settings